# IBM Lotus Traveler Server slowdown: how to correct "otus traveler 03 SERVICE UNAVAILABLE (The server is currently unable to handle a request) "

Tags: lotus-domino

I recently checked our log files for our traveler server (they are HUGE BTW) and noticed the following entries over the last few days:

Lotus traveler 03 SERVICE UNAVAILABLE (The server is currently unable to handle a request)

Most of these were on users that had reported having problems syncing mail.

What can I do to give the server more headway?

Answer (score 0):

I would look at tuning the HTTP threads.

The Domino HTTP server task must have enough threads to handle the number of HTTP requests from mobile devices accessing the Lotus Notes Traveler service. You can adjust the number of HTTP server threads using the Lotus Notes Administrator client and modify the server document for the Lotus Notes Traveler server. In the server document, click Internet Protocol, then click HTTP and change the Number of active threads value.

To determine the optimal number of HTTP threads to allocate for Lotus Notes Traveler, take the number of devices and multiply by 1.2. For example, if you have 250 mobile devices, then your HTTP active threads value should be at least 300 (1.2 times 250). The HTTP server task allocates all of these threads at startup time and keeps them active as long as the server is started. Do not over-allocate HTTP threads as this causes the Domino server to run out of memory.

Tuning active HTTP threads for Lotus Notes Traveler

Lotus Notes Traveler devices utilize Domino web server HTTP threads when communicating with the server.
If the number of active HTTP threads is insufficient, the following problems may occur:

```
Apple device users may experience "Cannot connect to server" messages or slow responsiveness when opening, sending, or synchronizing email, contacts, or calendar items and when downloading email attachments
Other device users may see error 503 (Server busy) messages in the Notes Traveler client interface, experience sync failures, and general slow responsiveness
Server CPU and memory utilization may increase to abnormal levels
```

The number of active HTTP threads needed for Traveler is calculated this way: 1.2 x Number of registered devices = Number of needed active HTTP threads
Default HTTP thread values activated by Lotus Notes Traveler

Lotus Notes Traveler will set the active HTTP threads to a default value depending on the architecture of the Domino instance.
For 32-bit Domino installations, 100 HTTP threads are allocated. This is done using the following notes.ini parameter, added automatically during Notes Traveler installation:

NTS_MAX_HTTP_THREADS=100

For 64-bit Domino installations, 400 HTTP threads are allocated. This is done via the following notes.ini parameter, added automatically during Notes Traveler installation:

NTS_MAX_HTTP_THREADS=400

These parameters are used to set the HTTP Number active threads value in the Server document during Traveler startup if NTS_AUTO_CONFIG=true is also present in notes.ini and the Traveler Server ID has appropriate ACL access to names.nsf.

Comment: Matt, this is very very good advice. I checked and our threads are really almost where they should be. I want to bump them a bit. But, what is odd is we are getting these errors for just two or three users. I can see hundreds of log entries, everything fine, but when I am refreshing one user's iPhone, that particular one keeps timing out. That seems like it is something with this user or his iPhone?

Comment: I would agree it could be a latency issue.  Are they connecting over Wifi or 4G?

Comment: Both. I was able to produce the error when we were connecting over WiFi right in the office. I also have new information. 1) We bumped up the threads but that didn't seem to help. I did notice that the particular user I was working with was not getting all of his contacts. I went into his $(Contacts) view in his mail file and updated all of his contacts - error gone. I get the feeling that a corrupt contact was causing this. Any way to check for corrupt contacts, or a contact with a bad character in it?

Comment: This technote documents some scenarios that can cause a failure http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21468986